# Implement custom protocol handler

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension which will allow to open URLs like `something://abc.def` but not simply redirect it to some other http URL like `Navigator.registerProtocolHandler()` nor open some application.

I want to send whole raw HTTP request

`GET / HTTP/1.1
...`

to websocket and then render received whole raw HTTP response (headers, body, etc).

I couldn't find documentation for this, unfortunately.

TL;DR I want to redirect some protocol requests to websocket and render page from  it's response.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @noogui problem is that I don't know what code to try or from what to start. because every documentation I encounter about custom protocol handler is either about registerProtocolHandler or application handlers.